# Remote Desktop Solution for Mac OS X 10.5 or 10.6 that disables the screen

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, remote-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I leave the remote screen locked when I ARD/VNC/etc. to my Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/51529/how-can-i-leave-the-remote-screen-locked-when-i-ard-vnc-etc-to-my-mac)

I just set up an iMac at work running 10.5 and want to get to my desktop remotely. I see that I can use VNC to accomplish this, but this shows my screen. Is there a remote desktop solution that allows me to get my desktop that locks the screen? I already have SSH turned on for CLI access.

Comment: Cheap solution: Write an AppleScript that turns down the brightness on the remote host. (Sorry, very cheap though.)

Comment: I thought of that, but on the iMac turning the brightness down doesn't shut the screen off like on the laptops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/welcome/access/freedom/3/?wt.srch=1&originid=5646&utpk=LogMeIn%20com&destination=/welcome/access/freedom/3/) will work for this, and has other options as well. I used it in a corporate setting with hundreds of PCs and it was great.  Will also let you get into PCs from Macs and vice versa. Also also, it is web based which means you don't need to have anything installed on the remote PC (if you are travelling or at another location without the software).

**EDIT:**

Free accounts (as of a few months ago) were limited in that they could not have subusers, and file transfer and advanced IT functionality was removed.

Answer (score 1):

Apple Remote Desktop does this, along with a whole lot of other useful administration stuff, but it's a long way from free.

Answer (score 0):

sure, Logmein does this. We use it for our tech desk and it's really nice.

They have a free version and it also disables the screen but I'm not sure of the terms to get a free account.