# Linux: Unlocking the display of a VNC session while leaving the physical display locked

Tags: linux, ssh, vnc

I'm connecting via ssh to an Ubuntu server that has a physical display attached.

I'd like the physical display of the server to remain locked while I'm connected remotely.

Is this possible? How?

Also, is there a way to automatically unlock the screen for the VNC session, which is made from localhost via an ssh tunnel?

Thanks!

Comment: [Disable local screen when remote VNC client connects](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/111418/44425), [VNC session with locked screen](https://superuser.com/q/407407/241386)

Answer (score 1):

A vnc server doesn't have to be attached to a physical display.  My recommendation is to start a vnc server on :1 on your remote Linux box and connect to that.