# Why can't I log in to a Windows system with TightVNC?

Tags: windows-10, tightvnc

I'm using TightVNC 2.8.5, connecting with TightVNC viewer on one Windows 10 system to TightVNCserver on another Windows 10 system.

If the server system is locked when the viewer connection is made, the viewer does not display anything. VNC viewer connects normally, and asks for the VNC authentication, but then the screen is all black, and it is impossible to enter the server machine's password and log in. I can see the server machine across the room, and the monitor wakes up when the viewer connects, and displays the password prompt. I attempted to type the server's password into the viewer (even though it was black), but the keystrokes were not echoed into the server's password field.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this question - - https://superuser.com/q/407407/302907

Comment: Does using the DFMirage Driver (video driver) help?  (Obtainable at https://www.tightvnc.com/download.php )