# Ubuntu: How to decouple the VNC server's screen from the physical screen?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vnc

I'd like to have my VNC sessions to a server use a separate display from the physical screen. So that e.g. I could have the physical screen locked in screensaver while the VNC display is unlocked.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here are [simple instructions](http://www.accessgrid.org/agdp/howto/vnc-ag-node/1.0.6/html/vncserver.html) that should apply to any linux distribution that has the vncserver executable on it. In a nutshell:

1. Create a VNC server password with `vncpassword`
2. Start a VNC server by calling `vncserver` with the options you want to use for the desktop (colour depth, screen size, sharing, etc.)
3. Connect to that instance (from the local machine or a remote machine) using any VNC client and the password you set in step 1.

Answer (score 1):

Start a session with vncserver. You'll have to make an executable shell script ~/.vnc/xstartup that starts some window manager and possibly some apps